# Navigate from EditText to Spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I have a signup form and between a few `EditText` fields, I have a `Spinner`. Here's how the layout looks now:

[image]

The field `High School Graduation Year` is the `Spinner` (had to made it look like an EditText). So, when I'm at the field `Password` and click on the Navigate-to-next softkey, the focus goes to the field `Zip Code`. I want the focus to go to the `High School Graduation Year`, so that the dropdown opens up. I tried adding this:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/graduationYear"
```

to my password layout, but it didn't workout. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I faced a similar problem not long time back. I added an `OnEditorActionListener` on the `EditText` as follows and it worked.

```
mPasswordEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                    mPasswordEditText.clearFocus();
                    mHighSchoolSpinner.requestFocus();
                    mHighSchoolSpinner.performClick();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```